# cycle through images until hover then set active image based on the link you are hovering over

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some links which relate to pictures. I can currently get the images to cycle through but I to make the active image change when hovering over the related link (ive made it so the related links and images have the same id). Here's my code currently:

```
function homepageCycle(){
    var $active = $('#homepage-images .active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#homepage-images img:first');
    $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(homepageCycle, 4000);
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the error/problem, or at the very least the HTML too?

Comment: Just add listener to images and in the listener check what was the event target